# Submit FormData without Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, form-data

I have an HTML form that I am using to register users. I am recording a file from the WebCam, and I need to upload the video file with the form.

Here is my code (it is working well):

```
$("#registration-form").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var recordedBlob = recordRTC.getBlob();
    var file = new File([recordedBlob], 'filename.webm', {
        type: 'video/webm'
    });
    var formElement = document.getElementById("registration-form");
    var formData = new FormData(formElement);
    formData.append('appbundle_participant[videoFile][file]', file);

    $.ajax({
        url: '',
        data: formData,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(data) {
            // do some stuff
        }
    });
});
```

Is it possible to submit the form in Javascript but with the same behavior than the click on the submit? So... no success or error function, just go the next page that the web server is returning.
Thank you very much.

Comment: Is there any reason why you want to not use AJAX?

Comment: The main reason is that if there is no error in the form, the server is doing a redirection, I don't have the control on this. The reason that follow this is that the answer is the entire HTML page and it's really dirty to reload the entire page with JQuery... Hope this is clear.

Comment: Can't you do a `window.location = '...'` on `jqXHR.done()`?

Comment: It is not a good solution as there is not the redirection if there is errors in the form.